# Is there OS X software for timed shutter release with a Canon 30D?

Tags: canon, timelapse, remote, shutter-release

I'm trying to do some time lapse photography with my Canon 30D, and I'm looking for a program for OS X that I can use to fire the shutter over time instead of using an intervalometer.

Does the EOS Capture utility have a timed shutter release function? Or do you know any other software with this feature?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but related: http://www.dpreview.com/news/1108/11080515androidtetheredapp.asp There apparently is an Android app that can do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOS Utility has this feature, at least the 2.5.1. version for Mac does. Simple and free... Click the clock icon:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you cant get onone software to work you might need to resort to the EOS software.
Someone demoing a 30d using that for intervals in this youtube link. That software is a nightmare to get working if you don't have the CD but if you have the software then I would say that is your best bet.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqwfR8o2JcA

---

I use One1 DSLR Camera Remote for exactly this.
http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/dslr-camera-remote/

It hooks your camera (in my case a Canon 40d) via the USB to my laptop, I've used it on a Dell and on my Macbook Air. In the case of my Air, I also bought the DSLR Remote software app for my iphone and over wifi could monitor the images on my phone.

You can also alter settings and trigger the shutter from your phone, eg. if you are in manual mode, you can change aperture and shutter speeds.

Comment: Very cool, unfortunately the latest version doesn't work with the canon 30D

Comment: Brutal, you could try their support and see if they will send you an older version if you pay for it. Can't see why they wouldn't.